# jQuery add div around table tr items which have specific attribute

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, word-wrap

I have a table with tr s where few of them have attribute active and few of them have attribute inactive. I am trying to group them. How can I add a div wrapper around  tr s with inactive attribute items.

**Current Code:**

```
    <div class="alertsList">
        <table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>time</th>
                    <tr class="alertRow" state="Active">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>1025973</td>
                        <td>SYSTEM</td>
                        <td>false</td>
                        <td class="Active">Active</td>
                        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="alertRow" state="Active">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>1025974</td>
                        <td>SYSTEM</td>
                        <td>false</td>
                        <td class="Active">Active</td>
                        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="alertRow" state="InActive">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>1025974</td>
                        <td>SYSTEM</td>
                        <td>false</td>
                        <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="alertRow" state="InActive">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>1025974</td>
                        <td>SYSTEM</td>
                        <td>false</td>
                        <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="alertRow" state="Active">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>1025974</td>
                        <td>SYSTEM</td>
                        <td>false</td>
                        <td class="Active">Active</td>
                        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Required: I am trying to achieve the below

```
<div class="alertsList">
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>time</th>
          <tr class="alertRow" state="Active">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="Active">Active</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>      
          <tr class="alertRow" state="Active">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025973</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="Active">Active</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow" state="Active">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="Active">Active</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>

**<div class="inAct">**
                <tr class="alertRow" state="InActive">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alertRow" state="InActive">
                    <td></td>
                    <td>1025974</td>
                    <td>SYSTEM</td>
                    <td>false</td>
                    <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
                    <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
                </tr>
      **</div>**
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't add a div around tr tags. It is semantically not good.

Comment: I suggest that instead of wrapping a `div` around a set of table rows, and giving your `tr` elements the invalid attribute `state`, you switch to giving the table rows the class 'active' or 'inactive' (either in addition to or instead of 'alertRow'). There is also no point in giving all the rows in your table the same class, `alertRow`. Better to assign the class to the table itself.

Comment: btw, instead of wrapping your `tr`s with a `<div>`, you can put them in a separate `tbody` element. That is actually a valid HTML practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the only valid parent elements of a `<tr>` element are `<table>`, `<tbody>`, `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` (*not* `<div>`), and the only valid child elements of those elements are `<tr>` elements (*again* not a `<div>`), I'd suggest not using a `<div>` (clearly).

That said, a `<table>` *can* contain multiple `<tbody>` elements, so I'd suggest using one of those instead:

```
// get the <tr> elements with the class of 'alertRow' and
// the 'state' equal to 'InActive':
$('tr.alertRow[state="InActive"]')
// wrap all those elements (together) in one <tbody>
// element, created here:
.wrapAll('<tbody class="InAct"></tbody>')
// wrapAll() returns the wrapped elements, we want the
// created-element, so we use parent():
.parent()
// we append that parent (along with its contained descendants)
// to the existing table:
.appendTo('div.alertsList table');
```

```js
$('tr.alertRow[state="InActive"]')
  .wrapAll('<tbody class="InAct"></tbody>')
  .parent()
  .appendTo('div.alertsList table');
```

```css
.InAct tr {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alertsList">
  <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>time</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" state="Active">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025973</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" state="Active">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" state="InActive">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" state="InActive">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" state="Active">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note that, while custom elements *work*, they are *not* valid (outside of HTML5), and *in HTML5* they are `data-` prefixed, to give the (valid) custom attribute of `data-state`:

```
<div class="alertsList">
  <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>time</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" data-state="Active">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" data-state="InActive">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- and so forth... -->
  </table>
</div>
```

With that amendment made, the above jQuery still pretty much works as-is, albeit the attribute-selector has to be modified to match the new custom attribute, giving:

```
$('tr.alertRow[data-state="InActive"]')
.wrapAll('<tbody class="InAct"></tbody>')
.parent()
.appendTo('div.alertsList table');
```

```js
$('tr.alertRow[data-state="InActive"]')
  .wrapAll('<tbody class="InAct"></tbody>')
  .parent()
  .appendTo('div.alertsList table');
```

```css
.InAct tr {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alertsList">
  <table width="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>time</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" data-state="Active">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025973</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" data-state="Active">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" data-state="InActive">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" data-state="InActive">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="InActive">InActive</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="alertRow" data-state="Active">
        <td></td>
        <td>1025974</td>
        <td>SYSTEM</td>
        <td>false</td>
        <td class="Active">Active</td>
        <td>2014-09-23T00:59:26.92</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't suggest wrapping your table rows with div's, but you can use [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to do this, not sure if they'll even be displayed, but here you go.

```
 $("tr.alertRow").wrap("<div/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), you can insert an HTML structure around the inner elements like so:

```
$(".alertsList table").find("tr[state='InActive']").each(function () {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='inAct'></div>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/kvyunto9/